# How to update bulk of customer address information?

Tags: magento-1.9, mysql, customer-address

I have one requirement to update the customer first name and last name in address information section. I tried through csv file import/export method but it only update in account information section not in address information such as billing and shipping address in admin panel(customer->manage customer section).

Currently few records in customer information section are present with lastname combine in firstname section (e.g firstname:- testtest1 and lastname:- blank instead of firstname:-test and lastname: test1)

and I want to split the firstname and lastname separately in address information section too.

So how should I proceed to solve this query to my bulk of customer.

Comment: need to update customer address information via csv or php script?

Comment: How do i update it through csv..?

Comment: Because I try to csv but it's not get updated..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go admin side `System -> Import/Export -> Export` and Export all customer with all data

After your exported csv file updates bellow header fields data

```
_address_firstname

_address_lastname
```

Go admin side `System -> Import/Export -> Import` and upload your updated csv file

**Make bellow settings :**

1. Entity Type * : Customer
2. Import Behavior *:  Replace Existing Complex Data
3. Select File to Import *: upload updated file

After click `Check Data` button if no error then click `import` button

**Note :** first backup your database

Comment: Thanks..I have useful this answer but I want to update only two fields that is first name and last name..But when I export it's shows all fields need to fill compulsory message.

Comment: Yes it is magento default functionality

Comment: If your use magento default Import/Export then customization ImportExport module otherwise your create own custom module for that

Comment: @Abdul, want to update only selected customer field like address,zipcode and state etc. so how i can import this field using csv file ?

Answer (score -1):

**Select File to Import *: upload updated file.**

Its not uploading only processing.